# Impala - How to get the third to last occurrence of a character within a string

Tags: impala, substr

I've the following string:

```
SELECT '00000-AAA1-1111-BBBB1-010101-CCCC1' as Word
FROM Table_A
```

I have the above string I only want to extract the string between the third-to-last and the last occurence.

Basically, I want to extract the following string:

```
'BBBB1'
```

I was trying with that but it gives me the wrong result:

```
 substr(Word, 1, length(a.cod_system_shipment_detail) - length(reverse(split_part(reverse(Word),'|',1))))

 "00000-AAA1-1111-BBBB1-010101-"
```

How can extract only BBBB1 from the above string?

Thanks!

Comment: it is not clear what you are expecting. what do you mean third to last and last occurrence? I would suggest add some additional explanation

Comment: From "'00000-AAA1-1111-BBBB1-010101-CCCC1'" I want to extract BBBB1. Before 'BBBB1' we have 3 special characters and 2 after.

Comment: before bbbb1 I see "1111-" not sure what you mean by specifial characters

Comment: special character: "-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split by `-` and get the third element, you can do it as follow

```
SELECT split_part('00000-AAA1-1111-BBBB1-010101-CCCC1', '-',4);
```